# In relation to "the two door riddle," what is which door either guard is guarding logically dependent upon?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Link to the two door riddle: https://nerdist.com/article/how-to-beat-the-labyrinth-two-door-riddle/

**Question**: In relation to "the two door riddle," what is which door either guard is guarding logically dependent upon?

**Proposed answer**: In relation to "the two door riddle," which door either guard is guarding logically dependent upon _____________ (I don't know).

**Research I've done**:

I'm drafting a legal petition I think would raise "the two door riddle" within the judge: [Link to a version of my poorly polished, not done legal petition](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Zs1cfzvxmI9rybrqQ073-y2u74dWypR-zYt1AumCGcI/edit?usp=sharing). It seems to me that using the two door riddle could become a standard for a judge determining whether or not to grant a petition/motion/etc., based on my analysis. This is from my preliminary that I considered today, and I'm *not* sure that it's accurate. I'm working up on proving fraud upon the court: Note, I'm not looking for legal advice here.

Regardless, I've looked into the liar's paradox and the Pinocchio paradox, whereby I'm assuming that either guard that states the answer in relation to the proper question is saying something like, "I'm lying," relative to the liar's paradox, whereby the resolve is to take the other door.

So, presuming the conditions of the riddle are in place, such as {1} there are two doors (a left door and a right door) and {2} I do not know which door leads where, then if I were to ask either guard, "What would the other guard say as to which door leads to heaven"? either guard might say, "The left door." From this, I'm supposed to interpret, that the guard is lying about which door leads to heaven, whereby the opposite door is the one that leads to heaven: Implicitly, the guard that is asked the question is saying, "I'm lying." Presuming that I want to go to heaven, then the door for me to take is the door on the right in order for me to get to heaven.

I've noticed something about this riddle that it appears a lot of people take for granted from the various webpages on the riddle that I've read. It appears there is a belief that any door is pre-determined and cannot be changed. For instance, it might be interpreted be argued that a left door or a right door leads to heaven, as though the door is pre-determined from the get-go. However, from my interpretation, based on who you ask the question to, the door by necessity can change.

For instance, it might be interpreted that from the beginning of the riddle that one of the doors leads to heaven (let's say the left door) and the other door leads to hell (let's say the right door). But for it to logically hold that the door to take is the contrary of what the guard says in relation to the question asked, then it has to be possible that the door that leads to either heaven or hell can change.

It appears to me that if **from the beginning** that the left door is the one that leads to heaven, then for some odd reason, when I ask either guard "What door would the other guard say leads to heaven?" and the guard responds, "The other guard would say that the left door leads to heaven," it will become a matter of fact that the left door all of a sudden becomes the door to hell (if but instantaneously upon asking the question if not at the point of the guard's response). Why is that? There is something that all of this is logically dependent upon, for which I cannot figure out. It's a logic puzzle to me, and my skills in logic are not that good.

Comment: "But for it to logically hold that the door to take is the contrary of what the guard says in relation to the question asked, then it has to be possible that the door that leads to either heaven or hell can change." - **No.** This is where you go wrong. You say the opposite of what the guard tells you because you are sure the guard is either lying or is accurately reporting a lie the other guard would say. Not because the door changes in response to the guard's answer.

Comment: By 'You say the opposite..." you mean "You take the opposite...," (presuming the opposite door is the one I want) right?

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to understand what exactly you're saying - this post is very wordy, and the linked legal petition even more so. But I think I've figured out where your misunderstanding lies.

> It appears to me that **if [...] the left door is the one that leads to heaven**, then for some odd reason, **when I ask either guard "What door would the other guard say leads to heaven?" and the guard responds, "The other guard would say that the left door leads to heaven,"** it will become a matter of fact that the left door all of a sudden becomes the door to hell (if but instantaneously upon asking the question if not at the point of the guard's response).

The bolded premises are contradictory. If the left door is the one that leads to heaven, then either guard ***must*** say "the right door leads to heaven". The conditions of the problem are that one guard must always lie, and the other guard must always tell the truth; what they speak is predetermined by those rules.

---

Let's look at a much simpler case, since I think the hypotheticals of the original puzzle are confusing here. Say there is only one guard, and we already know he always tells the truth, and two doors. What you're asking is essentially...

> If the left door leads to heaven, and I ask the guard "which door leads to heaven?" and he says "the right door leads to heaven", do the doors magically change?

the answer is "this scenario contradicts the given setup and so it cannot happen".

---

The guards' stated behaviour - they must *always* lie, or *always* tell the truth - is a fundamental requirement for the puzzle to work. The only way asking questions is useful is that the guards' responses are 'automated', in a sense: they perfectly follow the specified pattern of behaviour, and cannot (even hypothetically!) break from it.

If this were not true - if that ironclad guarantee was *not* given by the puzzle creator - [the puzzle would be unsolvable](https://blog.plover.com/math/logic/annoying-boxes-solution.html). The situation would devolve into "two people disagree, and one of them is trustworthy while the other is not". This is a situation that happens often in real life, but I find that applying the 'two doors' problem is rarely helpful: the untrustworthy party is typically going to say whatever helps their case, rather than perfectly inverting the truth.

Answer (score 3):

> In relation to "the two door riddle," which door either guard is guarding [is] logically dependent upon ...

**nothing**. In fact, that's the whole point of the riddle.

The riddle does not ask you to figure out which guard is guarding which door, or which guard is the honest one and which is the liar. It simply asks you to figure out which door is which, and the solution hinges on not knowing which guard you're asking the question. In the solution, it doesn't matter which guard you ask, because the question you're asking is crafted to give the same answer either way. Therefore, it also doesn't matter which guard is in front of which door, as long as the doors remain in the same places.

So let's address the moving-doors assertion in your last paragraph. The rules of the riddle are simply that one door is good and one door is bad, and you don't know which, and that one guard always tells the truth and the other always lies, and you don't know which. Now, in your example, where the door on the left is the good door, and you ask either guard "What door would the other guard say leads to heaven?", **neither guard would answer that the other guard would say the left door leads to heaven.** That would break the rules of the riddle. In fact, if the doors switched places in order to make the statement follow the rules, it by definition holds that **it did not follow the rules at the time the question was answered.** This is the case regardless of whether the doors *can* move.